# cancel sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: iphone, request

I have a problem.

I need cancel the last sendSynchronousRequest. The user push a character and I send the new request, but I need that the last request when de user push a caracter are cancel.

My request are:

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

Thank you for your help.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cancel it.

The calling thread is blocked while the connection is performed and data is downloaded, so you'll have to wait things out.

If you need to cancel the request before it finishes, you need to make the call asynchronously.